# 2D List Comprehension to For loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert the following list comprehension to a normal for loop, mainly because I don't quite understand how it works yet:

`board = [ [3 * j + i + 1 for i in range(3)] for j in range(3) ]`

Creates a 2D array with values: `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`

My code:

```
board = []
for j in range(3):
    for i in range(3):
        board.append(3*j+i+1)
```

Creates a 1D array with values: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The internal loop saves values ​​in the internal lists. The external loop stores the lists in the external list**

```
board = []
for j in range(3):
    board2=[]
    for i in range(3):
        board2.append(3*j+i+1)
    board.append(board2)
print(board)

[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

**Explanation**

simply in each cycle of the loop an element of the list is created. This is the simplest case:

```
[j for j in range(3)]
[0, 1, 2]
```

---

now in each cycle of the loop simply create a list with the index:

```
[[j] for j in range(3)]

[[0], [1], [2]]
```

---

Now we use the same mechanism to declare the internal list:

```
[[j for j in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
```

---

now we make the values ​​of the internal lists depend on the external index:

```
[ [3 * j  for i in range(3)] for j in range(3) ]
[[0, 0, 0], [3, 3, 3], [6, 6, 6]]
```

finally we increase depending on the internal index:

```
[ [3 * j + i + 1 for i in range(3)] for j in range(3) ]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use an intermediate list to store the results:

```
board = []
for j in range(3):
    row = []
    for i in range(3):
        row.append(3*j+i+1)
    board.append(row)

print(board)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the same line guys (@RaySteam and @ansev) how can I rewrite this :

```
def bitStr(n,s):
    if n==1: 
        return s 
    return [digit + bits for digit in bitStr(1,s) for bits in bitStr(n-1,s)] 

print(bitStr(3,'123'))
```

Using two for loops ?